# FBGraph API, page tabs trying to determine is user is an admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Here is my scenario.
1) I have a user that installs my page tab.
2) she adds a friend as an admin.
3) the friend now an admin, goes to the page settings and clicks on the "goto the app" link o in the pages admin.
4) that friend goes to the URL i have set up on my site for admin.
5) i make the friend install the app with basic permissions.
6) now when the friend comes to the admin page

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

I can see the information. i then try

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/".$pageID."?fields=access_token");
```

But all i get back is

```
page_info = Array
(
[id] => 183194625149248
 )
```

When the owner of the page does the same thing they get back

```
page_info = Array
(
[access_token] => stuff
[id] => 183194625149248
)
```

So i am wondering what step am i missing? I need to get the access_token so i can then go further and make sure this person is a valid admin for the page

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The `user` item in the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) passed to your App when the page tab is loaded will tell you if the current user likes the page, and if they're an admin of the page. If the user has authorised your app, you'll also get the access token for that user in the same request.

Comment: if the user clicks on the "goto app" in the page->edit_page->manage_permisions->apps,  a signed_request is not sent. Just the $_GET[fb_page_id]

Comment: If the user clicks “go to app”, they are taken to the _canvas_ page of the app – __not__ the page tab.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the manage_pages permission to get the info needed

Thanks all